# Use pseudo php rewriting with nginx

Tags: php, url-rewriting, nginx

I am currently working on a script which uses pseudo url rewriting. Url like `http://domain.com/index.php/admin` work fine on Apache servers, but fail to run on the nginx webserver.

Is there a way let the software run on nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your server {} block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}
```

EDIT:

Does it not work even with index.php in the URL? What are you using to pass the PHP script to PHP? This is what I use and URLs of that kind work for me:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # With php5-fpm:
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
```